# PHP - How can I get pack() to return a string that is the same as a regular string?

Tags: php, encoding, pack

I am not sure what the issue is. I assume it is an encoding issue. What I would like is for

```
pack('V', 0x41) == "A"
```

to return true. This is not the case even though the encoding from mb_detect_encoding() returns ASCII for both and both print "A" to the screen when echoed. The real issue is that when the packed string is included in a sql query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT item_name, item_description FROM items WHERE item_name LIKE '$querystr%'";
```

it fails to execute the query, even though when printed to the screen the strings are equivalent. This is for a CTF challenge I am creating, so yes, that code is meant to be vulnerable to injection.

Comment: Can you change `V` to `c`? Not clear about `CTF` but `var_dump(pack('c', 0x41) == "A");` is true so does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The V argument in `pack` takes 32-bit unsigned values(little-endian byte order) so  your call looks like

```
pack('V', 0x00000041) === "A\0\0\0"
```

You can use trim to get rid of the excess nulls you can use another option, for instance `c`

```
pack('c', 0x41) === "A"
```

Comment: trim() works, I am using 'V' so it can iterate over the whole stream that it is accepting word by word. I appreciate it greatly. I should have thought of that, thank you!